# Rain diverter on metal roof

Tags: roof, drainage, metal-roof

I have a standing-seam metal roof (without gutters), which pitches down over the front door. This causes a couple of issues:

- It is awkward to go out the door when it is raining, as you need to walk through a sheet of water. Yes, you will be going out into the rain, so I wouldn't expect to stay completely dry, but walking through a waterfall isn't always fun.
- It causes splashback when the rain hits the granite stoop in front of the door, causing lots of water to hit the door frame and siding around the door. This is causing water damage, and a good deal of this wood needs to be replaced. But before I do that, I want to solve the problem causing this.

I think a rain diverter might be a good solution here, so the rain goes down to the side of the door, and misses the granite stoop. However, the resources I've seen online only show installing a diverter on a shingled roof.

I live in an area that gets a good deal of snow in the winter, if that matters.

Can I install a diverter on a standing-seam metal roof? Is there a reason I shouldn't? Is this a job for a professional roofer, rather than a DIY homeowner?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot or do not want to install gutters? This is kinda what they're designed for - preventing erosion right at your foundation - with the added benefit that you don't get a waterfall over the doorways.

Comment: There isn't a specific reason, but I like the idea that over most of the roof, the water comes off evenly, rather than just at the corners, so it soaks into the ground more evenly. Also, without gutters, the snow slides off pretty smoothly (in large sheets, that sound like a dead body falling off the roof), and I'm afraid these sheets would rip the gutters off.

Comment: You may want to do a search for "metal roof snow guards" to prevent snow and _ice_ from coming off your roof and hitting someone and making a real dead body (or at least, hospitalized body). Also, the downspouts are supposed to direct the water _away_ from the foundation to prevent erosion that can damage your foundation. But, it's your house...

Comment: As far as "can you"? Well that depends on your abilities and the product you're looking to install. We don't know your abilities. Some folks here certainly could, others shouldn't get anywhere near a roof. That leaves this as opinion based, which is off-topic. "Should you" is also opinion based - you & I have different opinions on that. I think you'll find that gutters are the traditional solution to your problem and that other solutions are available, but might be custom made and that's up to you do DIY or hire out.

Comment: Your can/should points are certainly good. I'm not afraid of a ladder, and I've done some roofing work (with asphalt shingles) many years ago. I think the problem I'm having here (which led to the question) is that all the information I am seeing online, youtube, etc, shows the installation process for shingled roofs. I'd like to see what the process is to decide if it is something I could handle. Do you know of any links that would show me the installation process?

Comment: and thanks for the tip on "metal roof snow guards". I will look into that too!

Comment: If you really wanted to go for it (and it was architecturally harmonious), you'd consider a cricket above the door. I'd think you'd need a real roofer to cover it, though.